# Can trait objects of type IntoIterator be boxed and held inside of a structure?

Tags: rust

Can trait objects of type `IntoIterator` be boxed and held inside of a structure?  I've a situation where I'd like to store a vector of objects that can be turned into iterators.  My attempt at this was the code

```
struct Foo {   
    foo: Vec<Box<dyn IntoIterator<Item = usize>>>,
}                                                            
                 
fn main() {                                                                     
    let _ = Foo {                                                               
        foo: vec![Box::new(1..2), Box::new(vec![2,4,4])],                       
    };                                                                          
}
```

However, this does not compile and produces the error:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `IntoIter` (from trait `IntoIterator`) must be specified
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |     foo: Vec<Box<dyn IntoIterator<Item = usize>>>,
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `IntoIterator<Item = usize, IntoIter = Type>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0191`.
```

I am aware that most of the time when we want to use `IntoIterator` we instead pass a generic into the structure.  However, in this case, the items that I'd like to store do not have the same time.  As such, is there a way to store a heterogenous collection of objects that can all be turned into an iterator of the same type?

Comment: In your example's main function, the items in foo can be turned into an iterator of what type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're wanting to do doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  But it would be easy to box each `Iterator` instead of each `IntoIterator`.

```
struct Foo {   
    foo: Vec<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>>,
}                                                            
                 
fn main() {                                                                     
    let _ = Foo {                                                               
        foo: vec![Box::new((1..2).into_iter()), Box::new(vec![2,4,4].into_iter())],                       
    };                                                                          
}
```

The problem you're running into is that `IntoIterator` is defined like this:

```
pub trait IntoIterator {
    type Item;
    type IntoIter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
}
```

In order for the compiler to emit monomorphic code, you have to specify both the `Item` type and the `IntoIter` type in the `dyn` specifier in the declaration of the `foo` field.  But different types that implement `IntoIterator` have differing `IntoIter` types.

If it's really important to you to box up `IntoIterator` objects before they are actually turned into `Iterator`s, then you have to add a new wrapper that transforms all the diverse `IntoIter` types into a `Box<dyn Iterator>`.  Like this:

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

struct GenericIntoIterator<I: IntoIterator>(I);

impl<I: 'static + IntoIterator> std::iter::IntoIterator for GenericIntoIterator<I>
{
    type Item = <I as IntoIterator>::Item;
    type IntoIter = Box<dyn 'static + Iterator<Item = Self::Item>>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Box::new(self.0.into_iter())
    }
}

struct Foo {   
    foo: Vec<Box<dyn 'static + IntoIterator<Item = usize, IntoIter = Box<dyn 'static + Iterator<Item=usize>>>>>,
}                                                            
                 
fn main() {                                                                     
    let _ = Foo {                                                               
        foo: vec![Box::new(GenericIntoIterator(1..2)), Box::new(GenericIntoIterator(vec![2,4,4]))],                       
    };                                                                          
}
```